# Diifference between INA827AIDGK & INA827AIDGKR

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, texas-instruments, packages

Whats the difference between the same package of the IC INA827 - INA827AIDGK vs INA827AIDGKR?

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina827.pdf) makes no mention of any differences.

Except in in.element14.com

where INA827AIDGK is mentioned as 1 Amplifier, but
INA827AIDGKR is mentioned as 3 Amplifier.

Answer (score 4):

They are identical. The difference is the packaging, as described in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina827.pdf). Do not depend on distributor data- the manufacturer's data is the only one you should consider correct (and even then...)

[image]

INA827AIDGKR quantity 2500 is packaged in a full-size tape and reel

INA827AIDGK quantity 80 is packaged in a tube

Comment: Thanks for the information. The element14 website must have made some error.